# Django user daily updating model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm new in django. I want to create applications where users will be able to create objects and update them daily (add new days and new descriptions and photos).

So my question is:

1.

In models.py I need to create class Object(models.Model) and use ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) or OneToOneRel(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) to connect user which create object with this object ?

2.

I need to create an extra class day where there will be fields such as a subtitle description etc and add it to the object class?

3.
How I can create form or views to daily updating ?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand.

Comment: @almostabeginner I want to create app where a user can create object which can updating every day with new description etc

Comment: You want users to be able to create objects with a description field, and you want them to be able to update the description field everyday? Or do you want them to create objects that has description field and then you want the description field to change automatically everyday? I hope you understand why I find it hard to understand.

Comment: @almostabeginner that first. (I want users to be able to create objects with a description field, and I want them to be able to update the description field everyday)

Comment: What do you mean by everyday? Do you mean; update only once in 24 hours?

Comment: @almostabeginner no I mean user can update every time (I use wrong word)

Comment: In that case, you need to follow a django tutorial or even django docs. That is just a matter of creating the class with description field and user as foreign field. Then you either use django's admin, or create your own forms to handle login and change of description.

Answer (score 0):

1i. You need User and Objects model. You can use built in django [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/)
You have one to many relation one user can have many objects. Therefore you need foreign key. So make Object model like this:

`class Object(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    user = ForeignKey(model=User)`

2. Don't understand
3. Django provides you simple [admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/) which is suitable if you want to just add, update, delete. Otherwise you can use model forms to build your custom views and templates for edit database records. [Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)
   and [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/). Here you will find everything you need to create custom views with model forms.